# Tensorflow variables are not instantiated beforehand when the empty layer is created

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a new custom keras model for Keras. For calculating the loss, I am using Gradient Tape as suggested at https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow-2-0-d8fa35405e4e.
 However, I found that the variables are not initialized before the call operation. To give you a simple example.

```
l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(activation=None,    
                      units = 1,
                      input_shape = (10, ))
l.variables
```

There the variables are empty. But on calling

```
l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(activation=None,
                      units = 1,
                      input_shape = (10, ))
l(np.ones((10, 10)))
l.variables
```

The above code provides the list of variables. 
I was just trying to understand if this is expected behavior. In such cases, I should calculate loss before adding the variables to watch list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow/keras, layer weights do not get initialized when creating them (calling `__init__`), but when calling their `build()` method, or invoking the `__call__` method for the first time like you did with a zero tensor. You can read about it briefly here in the [Custom layers documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers), or in the [official source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1158).